# How to add a click function on an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I am trying to write a function so that when I click on an image it loads external content.

```
<section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg"></img>
</section>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lifeofpi").click(function(){
        $("#lifeofpi").load("lifeofpi.txt #p1");
    });
});
```

When I click on the image I want it to load this external content from a text document. But when I click on the image nothing happens.

Comment: Why are you loading a text file into an image? What do you want to happen exactly? Click the image and where does the content get added? I know you do not want it to be added as a child of an image since an image does not have children.

Comment: I just want it to load content about the image itself. For example if it is a movie. When I click the image it loads the txt file and gives details about the movie, For example year of publish, rating etc

Comment: So you need to add a target to where you want that content to go...

Comment: When I click the image I want to make it pop up a box with content about that image

Comment: Did you include jquery?

Comment: yes I did link the jquery

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load content into the image. You need to add it to an element that can actually have children.

```
<section class='images'>
  <img class="review-img" id="lifeofpi" src="./images/lifeofpi.jpg">
  <div id="lifeofpi_details"></div>
</section>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#lifeofpi").on("click", function () {
        $("#lifeofpi_details").load("lifeofpi.txt #p1");
    });
});
```

Comment: If I wanted to load a small pop up box would I use lifeofpi.html instead

Comment: No you would use CSS to make it a modal/pop over/tooltip etc. Or use a library that does that.

Comment: Well does your text file have an element with the id p1?

Comment: Yes the document does have a element with the id p1

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#lifeofpi").on("click","#p1 lifeofpi.txt",function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert(this.id);
});
```

Read about [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)